# PHP não executa OnClick return confirm

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, echo

Estou com problema para executar o javascript dentro do "echo" do PHP, ja fiz algumas alterações e o problema persiste.

Segue o código que estou usando:

```
 echo "<a href='excluir.php?id_edital=" . $pegar['id_edital'] . "; onClick='return confirm('Deseja realmente deletar o edital?')''><button id='submitdel'><img id='icon-trash' src='images/trash.png'> Excluir</button></a>";
```

Comment: a href não está sendo fechado! voce abre a aspa simples mas não a fecha.

Comment: Não falta um `'` terminando o valor de `href`? Basta olhar no HTML gerado e verificar a sintaxe.

Comment: e `onClick='return confirm('` está incorreto, é necessário usar scape: `onClick='return confirm(\"..\"'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na parte onde está onClick, veja que logo após a palavra confirm você tem outra ' (aspa simples), como ela foi utilizada como abertura da ação do onClick, você está fechando ela ali. Coloca uma (") aspas duplas com uma barra antes.

Ficaria desta forma:

```
echo "<a href='excluir.php?id_edital=" . $pegar['id_edital'] . "' onClick='return confirm(\"Deseja realmente deletar o edital?\")'><button id='submitdel'><img id='icon-trash' src='images/trash.png'> Excluir</button></a>";
```

Fazendo esta correção, acredito que agora funcione.